# Socket.io emit message on load

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've been having some issues emitting messages from the client to the server. I have a need to send emit to the client immediately after the page is loaded, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('chat message', 'test 2');
});
```

but calling emit like this causes 404 not found error ([firebug console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ1K7.png)). If I add a delay of at least 200ms it works fine but it doesn't seem to be a robust solution, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io();

    setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('chat message', 'test 2');
    }, 189);
});
```

It seems to be some kind of connection delay issue, I was wandering if anyone knows a better solution. I've already tried the following:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('chat message', 'test 2');
});
```

With this I still get the error. I've even tried some weird things like making the server send a message to the client after connection is established and still got the same result...

There's probably an easy solution to this I just can't find it